# How to fix character in webview javafx?

Tags: java

When I load page of website I seen this character like this ฀ such as thail language.  when I input something on youtube it happen on. I tried to fix this but it fails to fix I really don't know how to fix problem like this :(

Comment: Do you think you have understand or stated your problem completely? if not think about the thing which you don't know. welcome to SO!!, please read [mcve], add more context to your question with example, code trials you tried , errors you get etc..

Comment: According to my code charts, that character, U+0E00, is not a valid Thai character at all.  But U+0E01 to U+0E3A are valid.